# How to scrape flight costs from google flights into a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-flights

I am planning a trip within Europe in a couple of months and know I want to visit certain cities. In order to keep costs down, I want to make a spread sheet that lists flight prices from each city.

Example: [picture of goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytRze.png)

This sheet lists the cheapest flights from Madrid to all these destinations over the course of these dates. Instead of looking up each flight, and each date individually, I think it would be quicker to automate it. How could I go about scraping flight prices from google flights. IE: given origin, destination, and date - is there code that will find me the cheapest flight from google flights given this information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes there are a lot of code in github. Just google it. Put this search: cheapest flight from google flight github. And it will give you a lot of repositories. O write your own code with playwright for example. Good Luck!